# How can I run a taglib outside of a JSP page?

Tags: jsp, jakarta-ee, servlets, jsp-tags, taglib

Given that I have something like this on a JSP:

```
<cic:table listBeanParm="presbeans" showSelct="false" messageType="cicProductTable">
    <cic:column>
        <cic:title>A column title</cic:title>
    </cic:column>    
</cic:table>
....
<% TableModel tableModel = (TableModel)request.getAttribute( "cic.table.model"); %>
//tableModel used here
```

I can see that in the code associated with `cic:table` that it sets the attribute "cic.table.model" (obstacle: I have to decompile to see it...no source).

```
            public int doEndTag() throws JspException {
/*  47*/        request.setAttribute("cic.table.model", tableModel);
/*  48*/        init();
/*  49*/        return super.doEndTag();
            }
```

And it looks like the type heirarchy looks like this:

```
cicTable extends cicComponent
cicComponent extends BodyTagSupport
(cicComponent runs pageContext.getOut(), and we do not have a page!)
```

But even so, I tried several variations like this (doStartTag, doEndTag), but my calls always fail with a null pointer inside the compiled classes:

```
    System.out.println("type:" + request.getAttribute("presbeans").getClass().getName());
    cicTable aTable = new cicTable();
    aTable.setListBeanParam("presbeans");
    aTable.setShowSelect("false");
    aTable.setMessageType("cicProductTable");
    //int result = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    //try {result = aTable.doStartTag();} catch (Exception e) {System.out.println("doStartTag bombed: " + e.getMessage());}
    //System.out.println("doStartTag returned " + result);
    int result2 = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    result2 = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    try {result2 = aTable.doEndTag();} catch (Exception e) {System.out.println("doEndTag bombed: " + e.getMessage());}
// Always a null pointer on the line above
    System.out.println("doEndTag returned " + result2);

    TableModel tableModel = (TableModel)request.getAttribute( "cic.table.model");
```

What I'd like to do is find a way to convert what's going on in the taglibs on the JSP page to code that will run in a servlet.  **Is there a standard, cookbook, method to get the taglib stuff to run in a Servlet?**